# How to show multiple titles per note?

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation

Following picture shows a list of notes with a title and a body. The title is selected via a select field.

[image]

Now I got the requirement to implement multiple titles per note. How would you change the UI to realize multiple titles? I thought of two possible solutions:

[image]

1. Join the titles and seperate them by ,
2. Show an indicator of the amount of titles, click on edit to view all titles

What do you think?

Comment: Can you tell us what the purpose of multiple titles per note is doing to help the users of the application? Are these canned categories (similar to tags) to identify the substance of the note itself?

Comment: @MikeM An agent and a client meet and talk about different topics. The agent documents the conversation with a single (consultation) note. When multiple topics are discussed the agent wants to assign multiple titles to the note. The titles identify the substance of the note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options are reasonable. Is there a constraint for vertical space? Otherwise the title just wraps.

If space is a concern, you could use the '+2', but instead of making them click, use a hover tooltip, saving them a click:

[image]

Comment: Hover tooltip is a bad choice for more reasons here, some of them beeing: 
- it is not clearly signalised that there is option to hover the text 
- its is not clearly signalised from Information Architecture point of view that all 3 titles have same importance 
- on mobile hovering wont work
...

Answer (score 3):

"Recognitaion over recall" (as one of 10 Nielsen Heurestics) clearly suggests always leaving information disclosed if possible, as its less effort for the user to get all info without another action.

It is also in many frameworks and existing UIs, therefore in the mental model of your users also, that +2 option is offered when there is no space.

Thus having option to toggle more titles make sense only if there is no space.

For the separator, as comma can be interpreted as part of same sentence - my suggestion would be to use "/" or "|"